# Run JavaScript in Java

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a javaScript tag:

```
<!-- Begin ParsTools.com Prayer Times Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www2.parstools.com/oghat/oghatwhite.php"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    var CurrentDate= new Date(); 
    var JAT= 1;  
    function pz() {};
    init();
    document.getElementById("cities").selectedIndex=12;
    coord();
    main();
</script>
<!-- End Prayer Times code -->
```

I want to run this script in java and receive the html document that server sends in response. How can I do this? I also need to parse the received document and extract some special tags.

thank you.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way I know is using HtmlUnit.

```
WebClient htmlunit = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = htmlunit.getPage("http://www.google.com");

//executing the javascript and getting the new page
page = page.executeJavaScript("<JS code here>").getNewPage();
```

more info: http://www.aviyehuda.com/2011/05/htmlunit-a-quick-introduction/

Comment: Thank you; In this way I always have to first load a page(for example www.google.com); then execute my javaScript code in that html page. Is there any cleaner way to run javaScript code without need to this stage?

Comment: Use file:///index.html and have a empty file locally.

Answer (score 0):

Sajad/Future visitors,
You may look into [Jakarta Bean Scripting Framework (BSF)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bsf/) to run your javascript even as standalone code if using older java version (< 1.6, later versions of java have it embedded)