# Extract the content from the table using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am  trying to parse the following page.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(“http://www.informatik.unitrier.de/~ley/pers/hd/h/Han:Jiawei.html“).get();
```

I need to extract the contents of the 1st table, that is only author names and their publications. But I need only the contents of the table from the year 1986 to year 2012.
What could be the possible syntax in jsoup?

Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

The data of this website is using *javascript*, so it's not possible to parse it with jsoup.

I've listed some alternatives in this answer: [Trying to parse html hidden by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666453/trying-to-parse-html-hidden-by-javascript/14715242#14715242)

Comment: Oh..Thanx..But I have no idea about the alternatives that has been listed..Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: unfortunately not with jsoup. Hope this helps you a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060674/run-javascript-in-java and http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/execute-javascript-from-java/